# Flask - Bad Request The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand

Tags: python, mongodb, flask, pymongo

I'm trying to do a file upload & enter data task into my MongoDB using flask
but I had this error when I filled my form & upload the image:

> **Bad Request**
>   The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand.

my HTML code

```
    <form class="form-check form-control" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="{{ url_for('index') }}">      
          <label>Full Name*</label></td>
          <input name="u_name" type="text" class="text-info my-input" required="required" />
          <label>Email*</label>
          <input name="u_email" type="email" class="text-info my-input" required="required" />
          <label>Password*</label>
          <input name="u_pass" type="password" class="text-info my-input" required="required" />
          <label>Your Image*</label>
          <input name="u_img" type="file" class="text-info" required="required" /></td>
          <input name="btn_submit" type="submit" class="btn-info" />
    </form>
```

& my python code:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, url_for
from flask_pymongo import PyMongo
import os
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['MONGO_DBNAME'] = 'flask_assignment'
app.config['MONGO_URI'] = 'mongodb://<user>:<pass>@<host>:<port>/<database>'
mongo = PyMongo(app)
app_root = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))


@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    target = os.path.join(app_root, 'static/img/')
    if not os.path.isdir(target):
        os.mkdir(target)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        name = request.form['u_name']
        password = request.form['u_pass']
        email = request.form['u_email']
        file_name = ''
        for file in request.form['u_img']:
            file_name = file.filename
            destination = '/'.join([target, file_name])
            file.save(destination)
        mongo.db.employee_entry.insert({'name': name, 'password': password, 'email': email, 'img_name': file_name})
        return render_template('index.html')
    else:
        return render_template('index.html')

app.run(debug=True)
```

Answer (score 60, accepted):

The error there is resulting from a `BadRequestKeyError` because of access to a key that doesn't exist in `request.form`.

```
ipdb> request.form['u_img']
*** BadRequestKeyError: 400 Bad Request: The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand.
```

Uploaded files are keyed under `request.files` and not `request.form` dictionary. Also, you need to lose the loop because the value keyed under `u_img` is an instance of `FileStorage` and not *iterable*.

```
@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    target = os.path.join(app_root, 'static/img/')
    if not os.path.isdir(target):
        os.makedirs(target)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        ...
        file = request.files['u_img']
        file_name = file.filename or ''
        destination = '/'.join([target, file_name])
        file.save(destination)
        ...
    return render_template('index.html')
```

Comment: thanks mate your answered solved my problem. I had my html input text with NO property "name". After place that everything worked just fine. Here's the working code: <input
              class="form-control"
              id="userId"
              name="userId"
              placeholder="User Id"
              type="text"
            />

Comment: In my case, value of  name property of input tag was different in HTML and the key I was trying to access inside f = request.files['file'] was different. Changed both to "file" and it worked.